With slurm, how to allocate a whole node for a single multi-threaded process?
in my lab, slurm is configured with SelectType=select/cons_res. How may I run a multithread program in 1 node using all harts ?
I've tried:
sbatch -N 1 --ntasks-per-node=1 pz-train.batch

It doesn't work, only 2 harts are allocated and the configured memory for 2 harts (around 3800 MB). Confirmed checking the CPU affinity mask, slurm environment variables and sinfo shows mix for node state. It also crashes due to lack of memory.
Also:
sbatch -N 1 --cpus-per-task=56 --mem=100G pz-train.batch

These are the specs for one type of machine in the cluster, with 56 harts and 128 GB RAM. It works correctly, CPU affinity is all harts, memory usage is sufficient and sinfo shows alloc state. But when the allocation happens with the second type of machines, with 104 harts and 256 GB RAM, the remaining 48 harts are not available (the CPU affinity mask excludes them), but the multi-threaded program would benefit from them.
How to allocate a whole node for a single multi-threaded process ?

Use the --exclusive option of sbatch so that the full node is allocated to your job:
sbatch -N 1 --exclusive pz-train.batch


I've discussed that in the slurm mailing list and, even though I didn't originally want the allocation to be exclusive, I've concluded that slurm doesn't have an option to atomically fill a half-full node with 1 task. So the final command line used was: sbatch -N 1 --exclusive --ntasks-per-node=1 --mem=0 pz-train.batch
